# Como eu chamo no CSS uma variação de fonte?

Tags: css

Como eu utilizo a variação da fonte OPEN SANS?

Exemplo:

```html
<script src="//use.edgefonts.net/open-sans-condensed:n3,i3,n7:all;
        open-sans:n3,i3,n4,i4,n6,i6,n7,i7,n8,i8:all.js">
</script>
```

Quero utilizar a variação de fonte: `i3` e meu css está assim:

```css
font: 16px 'open-sans-condensed'
```

Answer (score 5):

No [Adobe Edge Web Fonts](https://edgewebfonts.adobe.com/), o estilo personalizado `i3` corresponde a `Light Italic` que deverá ser utilizado da seguinte forma:

```css
body {
  font-family: open-sans, sans-serif;   /* a fonte a usar e a font de fallback */

  font-weight: 300;                     /* "Light" == 300 */
  font-style: italic;                   /* "Italic" == italic */
}
```

[image: Captura de tela]

## [Utilizar fonts no CSS](https://edgewebfonts.adobe.com/help#using-fonts-in-css)

Segue a lista de referência completa para o `font-weight`:

- `100` Thin, Hairline
- `200` Extra Light
- `300` Light
- `400` Normal, Book
- `500` Medium
- `600` Semibold, Demibold
- `700` Bold
- `800` Heavy, Extra Bold
- `900` Black